# Не могу найти правильный путь из лабиринта путем обхода в ширину

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Если матрица:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 ];
```

Нужно найти путь от точки start до точки end, но двигаться можно только по ячейкам, которые не содержат единицу.

```
var start = [4,0];
 var end = [3,4];
```

Написала код, но его проблема в том, что в массив посещенных вершин он добавляет все, в которые может зайти. А мне нужно, чтобы добавлялись только те, которые ведут к выходу.

```
matrix = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 ];

 var start = [4,0];
 var end = [3,4];


function findWay(position, end)
{

    var queue = [];

    var visited = [];

    matrix[position[0]][position[1]] = 1;
    visited.push(position);
    queue.push(position);

    while(queue.length > 0){

        var pos = queue.shift();

        var direction = [ [ pos[0] + 1, pos[1] ], [ pos[0], pos[1] + 1 ], 
                    [ pos[0] - 1, pos[1] ], [ pos[0], pos[1] - 1 ] ];

        for(var i = 0; i < direction.length; i++){

            if (direction[i][0] < 0 || direction[i][0] >= matrix[0].length) continue;
            if (direction[i][1] < 0 || direction[i][1] >= matrix[0].length) continue;

            if (direction[i][0] == end[0] && direction[i][1] == end[1]) return visited;
            if (matrix[direction[i][0]][direction[i][1]] != 0) continue;


            matrix[direction[i][0]][direction[i][1]] = 1;
            queue.push(direction[i]);
            visited.push(direction[i]);

        }

    }

    return visited;

}

findWay(start, end);
```

Comment: Может если Вы ответите на эти вопросы, то они натолкнут Вас на решение. 1. А меняется ли у Вас direction вообще? 2. Чему равно matrix.length и это значение не выходит за matrix?

Comment: @IgorLut, спасибо за комментарий. Да в том то и дело, что для первой итерации while все работает. direction отрабатывает правильно и из 4-х возможных направлений у меня доступно только одно. Оно и записывается  в очередь. А вот когда дело доходит до обработки вот этого самого нового направления, мне просто возвращается массив с двумя ячейками и все. Он даже не заходит в for. Насчет matrix.length я уже исправила. Спасибо)

Comment: Кажется я поняла проблему. Оно все время использует начальную ячейку, а не самую верхнюю из очереди.

Comment: @IgorLut, теперь работает, но оно не находит оптимальный путь. Происходит просмотр всех доступных вершин  https://jsfiddle.net/qds61mb7/3/

Comment: Проблема в том, что Вам нужно менять direction каждый раз в цикле while, если ни одно условие не сработало. Представьте, что Вы - функция. Что происходит после выполнения этого кода?
 `matrix[direction[i][0]][direction[i][1]] = 1;
            visited.push(direction[i]);
            queue.push(direction[i]);` Вы заходите на новую итерацию цикла while с теми же условиями.

Comment: + Вы не поняли насчет `matrix[0].length`. В Вашем случае `matrix[0].length = 5`. Если подставить `5` в условие, то Вам оно подходит? `direction[i][0] < 0 || direction[i][0] > 5`

Comment: @IgorLut, нет не подходит. поэтому там стоит continue. переходим на следующую итерацию цикла for.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66069/discussion-between-igor-lut-and-kittycat-13).